# Weird NSButton creation

Tags: swift, nsbutton

I have a simple AppDelegate like this:

```
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate, NSWindowDelegate {

  @IBOutlet weak var window: NSWindow!
  @IBOutlet weak var field: NSView!

  let button = NSButton()
  let buttons = [NSButton(), NSButton(), NSButton()]

  func applicationDidFinishLaunching(aNotification: NSNotification) {
    button.frame = NSMakeRect(30, 60, 80, 25)
    button.title = "ok"
    field.addSubview(button)

    for index in 0...2 {
      let buttonI = buttons[index]
      buttonI.frame = NSMakeRect(30+CGFloat(index)*90, 30, 80, 25)
      buttonI.title = "not ok:\(index)"
      field.addSubview(buttonI)
    }
  }
}
```

(You can test the above by connecting `field` with a custom view inside the content view of the window).

When I run this I get the following button appearance:

[image]

Why is it that the single button looks ok while those from the array are not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to set the bezelStyle:

```
button.bezelStyle = .RoundedBezelStyle

buttonI.bezelStyle = .RoundedBezelStyle
```

Comment: This solves the issue but does not explain the behavior. The funny thing is that the `button` has that style already whilst `buttonI` needs an extra assignment although both are created the same way. Just that the latter is inside an array.

Comment: I could not reproduce it on my machine. All of them looks the same for me without it.

Comment: I restarted XCode more than once and kicked it then one or other way, that old head crash. I'll try a reboot too.

Comment: Nope. Using Version 6.1.1 (6A2008a) / 10.10.2 (14C109)

Comment: I did it using Swift 1.2 but I think it won't make a difference

Comment: So it's a bug in 1.1 >:-(

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/xpey7uascwgwgos/Screen%20Shot%202015-02-19%20at%2018.12.19.png?dl=0

Comment: You might need to delete your Xcode caches and derivedData

Comment: I did that already (I do that almost ever 5 minutes). Now downloading the beta 6.3. I ran the first of your projects and it shows ALL buttons wrong (or consistently the same way; just how you're looking on it). Just as in your picture. Now that is scary. Anyhow, back when 6.3 is here.

Comment: Beware of the Command failed due to signal: Segmentation fault: 11 error is really annoying

Comment: Ok. Too impatient. After a loong wait XCode came up (what did it do?). Converted to Swift1.2 and I see the same behavior. Probably if they fixed half of the 1300 open issues this is still one of the 650 left over issues. Thanks anyway for taking the time.

Comment: Well, it does not answer my original question but I honor the effort :-)